# Pcolormesh on basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a long list of latitudes and longitudes, and the ultimate goal is to plot the number of occurrences at each latitude/longitude pair on a map of North America.  As an example, I have a DataFrame, called sort_df, that looks like:

```
longitude  -95  -94  -93  -92
latitude
43           0    4    8    3
44           7    3    0    0
```

using sort_df.values and pmeshcolor, I can plot the data.  The code is as follows:

```
m.Basemap(llcrnrlon = -170, llcrnrlat = 10, urcrnrlon = -50, urcrnrlat = 80)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()
ny = sort_df.shape[0]
nx = sort_df.shape[1]
lons, lats = m.makegrid(nx,ny)
x,y = m(lons,lats)
my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')
my_cmap.set_under('white')
data = np.array(sort_df.values)
cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,data,cmap = my_cmap, vmin = 1)
m.colorbar(cs,extend = 'min')
plt.show()
```

The above code produces a plot that looks like:
[image]

The problem: There should only be colors on the lat/lon grid defined by sort_df.

Question: How do I make the grid appear in the correct spots on the map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a missprint while convert lat-lon. Your arrays `lats` and `lons` are empty.

Another problem of your code is that `data` have to have shape of [nx-1, ny-1] to plot with `pcolormesh` (it draw between points):

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pandas import DataFrame

m = Basemap(llcrnrlon = -170, llcrnrlat = 10, urcrnrlon = -50, urcrnrlat = 80)
m.drawcoastlines()
m.drawstates()

lon = np.array([-95,  -94,  -93,  -92, -91])
lat = np.array([43, 42, 41])
data = np.array([[0,4,8,3],[7,3,0,0]])
# you have to write just like here to convert coordinates
x,y = m(lon,lat)

my_cmap = plt.get_cmap('rainbow')
my_cmap.set_under('white')
cs = m.pcolormesh(x,y,data,cmap = my_cmap)
m.colorbar(cs, extend = 'min')
plt.show()
```

[image]